# PHP OCI: Connection string (convert from JDBC)

Tags: php, connection-string, oracle-call-interface

I have below obfuscated connection string in SQL developer which works:

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//xyz-scan.example.com:1521/mydb.example.com
```

How can I use this in php oci_connect?

```
$db = 'xyz-scan.example.com:1521/mydb.example.com';

$con = oci_connect('scott', 'tiger', $db, 'AL32UTF8');
```

Lead to error:

```
ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist
```

I can ping the server successfully.

I also tried

```
$db = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
   (HOST = xyz-scan.example.com)(PORT=1521))
   (CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)
   (SID=mydb.example.com)';
```

And instead of SID with service_name. Nothing works.
Above gives this error:

```
ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve the connect identifier specified
```

How do I convert this connection string to work with php oci? (is there a unique way? For a different db I have one with `@ldap://...` how would I convert that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to first issue with scan address is simple:

```
$db = '(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
(HOST = xyz-scan.example.com)(PORT=1521))
(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)
(SID=<sid>)';
```

The second one with ldap is not so simple. As far as I understood oracle has it's own ldap thingy and in it you store the databases TNS entries. This means you query it like you query any ldap system:

```
<?php
$ds=ldap_connect("oid.mydomain.com", myport); // Connect to oracle ldap
$r=ldap_bind($ds); // Bind to ldap
$sr = ldap_search($ds, "cn=OracleContext,dc=xyz,dc=abc,dc=com", "cn=dbname"); // Run query xyz.abc.com
$info = ldap_get_entries($ds, $sr); // Get entries
ldap_close($ds);
$dbconnectstring = $info[0]["orclnetdescstring"][0]; // Extract db connect string from ldap search result array 
$con = oci_connect('scott', 'tiger', $dbconnectstring);
?>
```

This script will get full TNS connection string which you can then use with oci_connect.